# Putting two Tikz Images Side-by-Side

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphics

I am trying to make these two images appear side-by-side.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]

\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2,line width=1pt]
\begin{axis}[
color= gray,
xmin=-9, 
xmax=9, 
ymin=-9, 
ymax=9, 
axis equal image, 
axis lines=middle, 
xticklabels={}, 
yticklabels={},
font=\scriptsize,
ticks=none,
xlabel = $x$,
ylabel = $y$,
inner axis line style={stealth-stealth}
]

\draw[blue, fill=blue, fill opacity=0.20, dashed] plot [smooth cycle] 
coordinates {(-6,0) (-4,2) (-3,6) (-1.5,6) (1,4) (3,6) (5,2) (2,-1) (4,-4) 
(3,-5) (0,-6) (-3,-5)};
\filldraw[black] (3,6) circle (0pt) node[above right] {$D$};
\filldraw[black, fill opacity=1] (-2,-2) circle (1.5pt) node[above right] 
{$z$};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\qquad

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2,line width=1pt]
\begin{axis}[
color= gray,
xmin=-9, 
xmax=9, 
ymin=-9, 
ymax=9, 
axis equal image, 
axis lines=middle, 
xticklabels={}, 
yticklabels={},
font=\scriptsize,
ticks=none,
xlabel = $u$,
ylabel = $v$,
inner axis line style={stealth-stealth}
]

\draw[black, ultra thin, dashed] (0,0) circle [radius=5];
\draw[black] (-3.525,3.525) circle (0pt) node[above left] {$|f|$};
\filldraw[black, fill opacity=1] (3.525,3.525) circle (1.5pt) node[above 
right] {$f$};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\caption{Mapping a point $z=x+iy$ in $D$ onto $f=u+iv$ when $|f|$ is 
constant.}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Right now, this is how the figure compiles:

[image]

I would like to have the two graphs in this picture side-by-side, as opposed to them being on top of each other. I tried using the `\qquad` command but to no avail.

Any suggestions?

Comment: As with normal text, an empty line signifies a paragraph break. A new paragraph means a new line. Don't have paragraph breaks between the `tikzpicture`s.

Comment: Perfect, a silly oversight on my part. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have empty lines between the pictures, which get interpreted as ends of paragraphs, which means they introduce line breaks. If you get rid of them, and use a slightly wider geometry (e.g. the one that comes automatically when loading the `geometry` package), your pics are side by side.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]

\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2,line width=1pt]
\begin{axis}[
color= gray,
xmin=-9, 
xmax=9, 
ymin=-9, 
ymax=9, 
axis equal image, 
axis lines=middle, 
xticklabels={}, 
yticklabels={},
font=\scriptsize,
ticks=none,
xlabel = $x$,
ylabel = $y$,
inner axis line style={stealth-stealth}
]

\draw[blue, fill=blue, fill opacity=0.20, dashed] plot [smooth cycle] 
coordinates {(-6,0) (-4,2) (-3,6) (-1.5,6) (1,4) (3,6) (5,2) (2,-1) (4,-4) 
(3,-5) (0,-6) (-3,-5)};
\filldraw[black] (3,6) circle (0pt) node[above right] {$D$};
\filldraw[black, fill opacity=1] (-2,-2) circle (1.5pt) node[above right] 
{$z$};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\qquad
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2,line width=1pt]
\begin{axis}[
color= gray,
xmin=-9, 
xmax=9, 
ymin=-9, 
ymax=9, 
axis equal image, 
axis lines=middle, 
xticklabels={}, 
yticklabels={},
font=\scriptsize,
ticks=none,
xlabel = $u$,
ylabel = $v$,
inner axis line style={stealth-stealth}
]

\draw[black, ultra thin, dashed] (0,0) circle [radius=5];
\draw[black] (-3.525,3.525) circle (0pt) node[above left] {$|f|$};
\filldraw[black, fill opacity=1] (3.525,3.525) circle (1.5pt) node[above 
right] {$f$};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\caption{Mapping a point $z=x+iy$ in $D$ onto $f=u+iv$ when $|f|$ is 
constant.}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I also added `showframe` to indicate that the pics just fit, almost magically.

Comment: Is it possible to add `(a) (b) ` bottom of the each image?

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to place the two figures side by side within the `tikzpicture` environment by placing the second figure within a `scope` environment that is horizontally moved `\begin{scope}[shift={(6,0)}]`

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]

\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2,line width=1pt]
\begin{axis}[
color= gray,
xmin=-9, 
xmax=9, 
ymin=-9, 
ymax=9, 
axis equal image, 
axis lines=middle, 
xticklabels={}, 
yticklabels={},
font=\scriptsize,
ticks=none,
xlabel = $x$,
ylabel = $y$,
inner axis line style={stealth-stealth}
]

\draw[blue, fill=blue, fill opacity=0.20, dashed] plot [smooth cycle] 
coordinates {(-6,0) (-4,2) (-3,6) (-1.5,6) (1,4) (3,6) (5,2) (2,-1) (4,-4) 
(3,-5) (0,-6) (-3,-5)};
\filldraw[black] (3,6) circle (0pt) node[above right] {$D$};
\filldraw[black, fill opacity=1] (-2,-2) circle (1.5pt) node[above right] 
{$z$};

\end{axis}

%\end{tikzpicture}
%
%\qquad
%
%\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2,line width=1pt]

\begin{scope}[shift={(6,0)}]
\begin{axis}[
color= gray,
xmin=-9, 
xmax=9, 
ymin=-9, 
ymax=9, 
axis equal image, 
axis lines=middle, 
xticklabels={}, 
yticklabels={},
font=\scriptsize,
ticks=none,
xlabel = $u$,
ylabel = $v$,
inner axis line style={stealth-stealth}
]

\draw[black, ultra thin, dashed] (0,0) circle [radius=5];
\draw[black] (-3.525,3.525) circle (0pt) node[above left] {$|f|$};
\filldraw[black, fill opacity=1] (3.525,3.525) circle (1.5pt) node[above 
right] {$f$};

\end{axis}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\caption{Mapping a point $z=x+iy$ in $D$ onto $f=u+iv$ when $|f|$ is 
constant.}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: scope]